# Windows Networking

Tags: networking

i have a very simple network of about 60 computers connected with each other through simple 192.168.1.X network, joined through workgroup. is it possible, somehow, to allow two folders to be shared on network, while one of them is accessible and other can only be accessible/ opened from specific computers, though it is visible by everyone. this so called locked folder should not open at other networked computers even after using the correct login credentials..and can only be accessed from specific computers with same login details.
Regards,

Comment: Typicaaly i thought if you have over ~20 PC's on a workgroup you need a domain. I'm amazed this works although it is interesting to know it does.+1

Comment: :) sounds good dave... and yes.. it is working fine . though i need to solve this thing out...u think u can help me with this?

Comment: At the moment, my answer is no, not with Windows alone. I am sure you can either share with all or no one. Although you didn't state what OS your network is on. However, there could be third party tools but I would have to Google it. Now, another way around this though could be passwords and giving passwords to those users who need the access (although a domain is designed for this)

Comment: dave, by assigning a password will open that folder at any pc, right...?? i don't want this..infact to be honest, i have this one folder with this configuration made by a co-worker, and i want to explore it. appreciate your help...

Comment: ACLs on Windows file shares and file systems can only identify the clients by user. There's the computer account, but it only gets used with programmed logged in as system/network service and trying to access resources in a domain. This use case is so rare, I doubt anyone would want to write anything specifically for that.

Comment: Yes sarib, it was a work around as the only way I know of is with a domain. We had the same situation and a server was the answer!

Comment: ahaan.. well, i guess domain it is then..